# Does anyone know how to install Sogou on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: keyboard, chinese, pinyin

I am trying to install Soguo on Ubuntu 16.04 so that I could write Chinese characters.

I have found this website: http://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/help.php

It is a walkthrough of how it is done, but it is in Chinese. I still don't speak enough Chinese to understand it. Does anyone know how to do the installation?

Comment: I don't speak ANY Chinese. Fortuantely Google has a translation service that is better than nothing.... See https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/help.php&prev=search

Comment: I am not looking for a translator. I am trying to write things in Chinese characters using a normal European keyboard.

Comment: My apologies for any confusion you may have experienced. I was merely pointing out that the [walkthrough](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/help.php&prev=search) that you found and did not understand could be translated so that you might be able to answer your own question with a minimum of effort.